# Maintaining OSGi bundle's state manually

Tags: osgi, blueprint-osgi

Is there any approach via we can maintain and control OSGi bundles' state manually via code?
I have a requirement where in I need to download, copy and install/activate/deactivate/delete OSGi bundles in run time environment.

Any help/references will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You install a bundle with BundleContext.install by supplying a URL or an InputStream. As result you get a Bundle. In Bundle you can then call start(), stop() and uninstall(). You get the BundleContext inside the Activator of any already existing bundle.

http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/BundleContext.html

Comment: Thanks Christian! So I understand it is also possible by using blueprint?

Comment: If you mean that you use blueprint in the bundle that controls the other bundles then yes it works. In blueprint you can inject the BundleContext into your class and then work on it like I described.